# Quarter valuations. Please help explain this to me

Tags: wordplay

Please help me understand US Quarter valuations.

Why are 1975 US Quarters worth more than 1974 US Quarters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because

> There is one more us quarters,those are numbers not years

Comment: Good job! You were quick! It wont let me accept your answer yet. I was hoping some people would be confused and assume I was off by ten years in trying to make a reference to the depreciated use of 90% silver

Comment: No, I don't process years well.

Comment: It just snapped in my brain as numbers